# How to disable the guest service peripheral device in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, pci

Virtualbox emulates a device called "guest service" for a Linux virtual machine that I need to minimize vulnerability to VM escape. The device allows mouse integration to work which is unwanted. The guest system is a Linux and host is Windows 11.
I have disabled the USB controller, audio controller, network controller and set the mouse type to PS/2, but the peripheral is still shown by lspci:

[image: peripheral device]

Searching Google or virtual box source code does not return any results about this device.
I also tried to disable paravirtualization interface and EFI, but did not work to disable the device.

```
00:04.4 System peripheral [0880]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service [80ee:cafe] Control: 1/0+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV+ VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL-fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort->SERR- <PER Latency: 0
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 20
Region 0: I/0 ports at c000 [size=32]
Region 1: Memory at e8000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
Region 2: Memory at e8400000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Kernel driver in use: uboxguest
Kernel modules: vboxguest
```

The device also interferes with Gnome login manager, it locks up when Virtualbox attempts to  use this device to enable mouse integration.

Is there a way to disable this device permanently, for Virtualbox or for a specific virtual machine?

Comment: I am asking for a way to disable the interface that guest extensions uses to communicate with the host because it is causing problems.

Comment: Guest extensions were never installed, USB pass through is disabled but the guest service interface is still provided to the VM.

Comment: `Kernel driver in use: vboxguest` You can try blacklist the `vboxguest` module. `Guest extensions were never installed.` Note that upstream kernel has a set of guest drivers / modules for virtualbox (with `vboxguest` being one of them), although AFAIK they are not exact clone of guest kernel modules / drivers shipped in the guest addition from Oracle.

Comment: That worked by adding modprobe.blacklist=vboxguest, but the original question was about a way to disable this interface in the host, maybe with VBoxManage.exe, because I have some virtual machines where adding this flag can be difficult and could cause security problems because the command line arguments can be removed by a malicious process.

Comment: `disable this interface in the host` I doubt that it's possible. (But well, I haven't really dug.)

Comment: For future reference - please don't post text as images. They can be difficult to interpret, and it's impossible to copy-paste for example search terms from them. Instead paste it directly as text, and enclose the output (or commands) in the code brackets `{ }` on the top bar of the edit box. The question mark on the right corner of the top bar shows you how to use the basic markups, more advanced info is available in the [Help Center](https://superuser.com/help).